# Not understanding the ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, recode

I'm trying to recode a variable based on two other variables and I think I'm misunderstanding how the `ifelse` statement works.

I have one column that is a string and then other is an integer. I want the new column to be the same as the string `c1` unless the integer column `flag` equals 1, in which case it will equal `XX`.

```
  c1      flag    EXPECTED OUTPUT
  SS         0          SS
  SS         1          XX
  MM         0          MM
  LL         0          LL
  LL         0          LL
  SS         1          XX
  LL         0          LL      
  LL         1          XX
  SS         0          SS
```

I'm using `ifelse` as such:

```
df$expectedoutput <- ifelse(df$flag==1, "XX", df$c1)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do a recode.

When I ask to view the new column I get this error:

```
Error in View : 'names' attribute [1849] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current output exactly?

Comment: You probably have a factor variable and not a string.

Comment: When I put `df$string <- as.character(df$string)` I get the same problem.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data using the dput function.  Something like dput(head(df, 10)) would help us understand your question and data better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were bitten by `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`. This seems to give the expected output:

```
df <- read.table(text="
c1      flag
SS         0
SS         1
MM         0
LL         0
LL         0
SS         1
LL         0     
LL         1
SS         0", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$expected <- ifelse(df$flag == 1, "XX", df$c1)

> df
  c1 flag expected
1 SS    0       SS
2 SS    1       XX
3 MM    0       MM
4 LL    0       LL
5 LL    0       LL
6 SS    1       XX
7 LL    0       LL
8 LL    1       XX
9 SS    0       SS
```